# How much time is a multithreaded program spending on heap contention?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, profiler, context-switch

I have a multithreaded MacOS C++ program that is running slower than expected. I think the reason is heap contention, because each thread is calling "new" or an equivalent many times, and the program runs faster when the threads are in separate processes.

How can I find out how much time the threads are wasting in heap contention?

Comment: You might try to use some other `malloc`

Comment: You run profile your program with the Time Profile template of Instruments. Look for wall-clock (not CPU) time spent in memory functions (e.g. `malloc()`, `free()`, etc.), especially in thread synchronization primitives called by them.

Comment: OK thanks. I guess these are in XCode? (I use command line tools)

Comment: Instruments *can* be launched from Xcode, but it's a separate app (although it is located inside the Xcode app bundle). There's also an `instruments` command-line tool to collect the data, but you'll have to use the Instruments app to examine it.